# Effect size for two-way ordinal ANOVA with cumulative link model

Tags: r, effect, ordinal, two-way

I am looking for an effect size measure that is suitable for a two-way (2x2) ordinal ANOVA with cumulative link model.

I have seen the functions `rank_eta_squared()` and `rank_epsilon_squared()` but in my understanding and after trying, they only work for one-factorial designs. Is there anything comparable for two-factorial designs?

What I have done so far is estimating my model with `clm()` function, displaying wald chi square statistics and tests for main effects and interaction with `anova()` function and then calculating **Cramers V** with `sqrt(chi²/n*df)` while df is always 1. Is this an acceptable approach?

Thanks!

Edit Example:

```
library(ordinal)
n <- 100
dat <- data.frame(IV1=sample(LETTERS[1:2], n, replace=TRUE),
                  IV2=sample(LETTERS[3:4], n, replace=TRUE),
                  DV=factor(sample(1:6, n, replace=TRUE), ordered = TRUE))

mod <- clm(DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + IV1:IV2, data = dat)
anova(mod)
sqrt(anova(mod)[2]/nrow(dat)) # Cramers V
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Sure, I edited an example.